# cogroup two RDD in scala

Tags: java, scala, collections, apache-spark, iterable

I am trying to cogroup two RDDs in my function for some calculations. My code is below:

```
def myCogroupFunction(teachers: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Teacher], students: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Student]) {

    val teacherPairs = teachers.map { t =>
      val nameKey: String = t.getName()
      (nameKey.toUpperCase(), t)
    }

    val studentPairs = students.map { s =>
      val nameKey: String = s.getName()
      (nameKey.toUpperCase(), s)
    }

    teacherPairs.cogroup(studentPairs)
  }
```

---

However, I got errors saying:

> value cogroup is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, com.abc.Teacher)]

What did I do wrong here?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, unless you are using an older version of Spark, in which case you need to import the implicits that make this possible via:

```
import SparkContext._
```